# AKS with Windows containers for Sitecore - anti-malware protection

Tags: sitecore, azure-aks, windows-container, antimalware

I want to migrate a Sitecore from Azure App Service infra to an AKS infra but I was told there was no anti-malware protection for Windows Container on AKS.

I haven't been able to find concrete information on this online.

Could you please tell me whether Windows containers have no anti-malware protection?

Do you have any idea what would be the impact of hosting a Sitecore website on AKS without protection ?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Quick clarification: What do you mean by anti-malware protection provided by App Service? Windows containers run in process isolation mode and rely on the anti-malware protection from their host. App Service and AKS run Windows Server hosts to run Windows containers and this enabled on both by default, so I'm not sure if you're looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure containers on Azure Kubernetes Service to have anti-malware protection, use [Microsoft Defender for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-enable?tabs=aks-deploy-portal,k8s-deploy-asc,k8s-verify-asc,k8s-remove-arc,aks-removeprofile-api&pivots=defender-for-container-aks), previously known as Microsoft Defender for Kubernetes, provides comprehensive security for containerized environments, including AKS.

To enable that, Go to [Azure Defender Plan](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Security/SecurityMenuBlade/pricingTier) page -> on the left side click on `Environment settings` -> `select your subscription` -> `Defender Plans` -> `Select Containers` -> turn on the security parameters which you want to enable along with the `container vulnerability assessment`.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Reference Documents:

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-enable?tabs=aks-deploy-portal,k8s-deploy-asc,k8s-verify-asc,k8s-remove-arc,aks-removeprofile-api&pivots=defender-for-container-aks)

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/defender-for-containers-introduction)